# Can I produce a native exe using flash builder and air

Tags: air, flash-builder

Can I produce a native exe using flash builder and air.

I don't want the user to have to get any other dependencies such as air etc. I want everything bundled into a native application, a single exe perhaps that I could produce my own installer using nullsoft or similar.

I've searched around and spoken to people and come to the conclusion that no one is sure, seen some yes and no's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With flash builder 4.6 they have included the captive build process in the gui. This enables you to produce an exe that is bundled with the AIR Dll's and requirements without the end user ever needing to install Adobe AIR.

Answer (score 2):

Correct: Flash Builder 4.6 has the option right there in the Project menu option, when selecting "Export Release build"   :-)